Short animation made with a particle instance need to have random colors but with my setup they change color every frame
I made this setup for the particle animation


As you can see in the video the particles are flickering between the colors.
I need them to have different colors that are not changing over time.

I think you need to have the geometry nodes "before" the particle system in the list of modifiers... it doesn't make much sense to take a point info before having points.

The only thing that Point Info > Random guarantee, is to have a random value per point. If points are created or removed (change in the number of points), this random value will change. I'm not sure what to advise, I've never use particle systems and GN together. There may be other conditions under which the random value changes.
